# How can I make a list with actions complety dynamic in XML (current solution: 3 arrays)

Tags: android, xml, android-recyclerview

I would like to make a main menu that will be different depending on a user preference.

Right now, I made different sets of array in my XML values for title, icon and string in order to populate a recyclerview.

So it looks like this:

```
<string-array name="titlelist_A">
    <item>Item 1</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    <item>Item 2</item>
    ...
</string-array>

<integer-array name="iconlist_A">
    <item>@drawable/ic_menu_item1</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_menu_item2</item>
    <item>@drawable/ic_menu_item3</item>
    .....
</integer-array>

<string-array name="actionlist_A">
    <item>Activity1</item>
    <item>Activity2</item>
    <item>Activity3</item>
    .....
</integer-array>
```

In my adapter constructor, I will pass all these arrays that I duplicated (A,B,C,D,E,...) in order to pass the corresponding array to user preference.

In my RecyclerView adapter, I use these arrays to set the title, the drawable, and the OnClickListener

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(MenuViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.title.setText(titleList[position]);
    holder.icon.setImageResource(iconList.getResourceId(position,0));
}
```

This seems like an heavy solution and I was wondering if some people have been in front of a similar issue and what they found...

Answer (score 1):

Ok, i finally used an Menu:

```
    PopupMenu p = new PopupMenu(context, null);
    menu = p.getMenu();
    context.getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_b, menu);
```

and in my adapter:

```
    MenuItem item = menu.getItem(position);
    holder.title.setText(item.getTitle());
    holder.icon.setImageDrawable(item.getIcon());
```